# Custom CSS being overridden

Tags: css, wordpress

Site URL: http://www.midwestcleancomedy.com

Please advise on the best way to present my question and the info you need as I'm a beginner. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/pandathorax/pen/RWbPGN?editors=011) I created that just has my custom CSS at the top, and the parent theme CSS which starts at line 252

I've cleared my cache, enlisted WP designers, and they were unable to pinpoint what is going on. Some of my early custom CSS worked, but most of it is being ignored, even if it's at the bottom of my stylesheet with !important as a last resort.

Since this happens many places, I feel like once I find the issue it will hopefully lead to solving others. It's now affecting nearly every change I want to make.

Current issue: Making my site responsive at the mobile width,

```
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 479px) {

. container .et_header_style_left #logo {
max-width: 80% !important; 
float: left;
     }
}
```

Just trying to get the logo on the left and the menu icon on the right, same line, but nothing I try seems to change the logo width or the menu's left padding: 175px.

Comment: Well your css selector looks incorrect. First `. container` shouldn't have a space, it should be `.container`. Second `.et_header_style_left` is a class on the `body`. So the correct selector should be this: `.et_header_style_left .container #logo`

Comment: Unfortunately, correcting that silly mistake--even for me--still did nothing to the CSS. Thanks for pointing that out nonetheless. I've corrected the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I had someone look at my style sheet, and it was a mess. I don't know exactly what they did, but they said there were formatting errors everywhere. @media issues abounded. Sorry I can't be much more specific, but basically I had to start a brand new style sheet and make much better notes. Thanks to everyone who responded.